# Protecting my PC in unknown WLAN/LAN networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security

[I once read in another thread on superuser that PCs in a network could try to acess services running on other PCs in the same network](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46533/are-there-risks-associated-with-connecting-to-a-public-hotspot)

Is it considered to be safe enough to enable ufw and deny all incoming connections when using an unknown network on a Ubuntu PC with a strong sudo password or is there more that one should take care of?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it considered to be safe enough to enable ufw and deny all incoming connections when using an unknown network on a Ubuntu PC

You should also consider that on an unknown network, it's possible that another system on that network could be monitoring all traffic that passes on the medium (much more likely with wireless than wired) and/or performing various attacks to spoof hosts.  Both of these tactics can be used to view traffic leaving and going to your PC and get information such as passwords, etc. that you would normally believe private.

To mitigate this:

- Restrict important/sensitive communication on untrusted networks to SSL traffic.  There are addons for Chrome and Firefox that force `https://` when possible.
- Ideally, you should know the thumbprint of the SSL certificates of any domains you expect to connect to through the untrusted network, BEFORE you get on the untrusted network.  This will let you discover any attempted man-in-the-middle attack with a spoofed certificate.  Compare thumbprints the first time you connect to such a domain on an untrusted network.
- If you encounter a certificate error on an untrusted network, either don't proceed, or compare thumbprints and ensure that you are connecting to your expected host - which you are likely not if you get a certificate warning.
- Use VPN servers (Virtual Private Networks) or similar technologies (IPSEC, Tor, SSH...) which encrypt your traffic through the potentially insecure LAN. By this you can at least avoid being sniffed using the WiFi or even cable connection.

Answer (score 0):

(I have never used UFW, but I am expert with IPTables which its based on, and UFW claims it only allows outbound connections by default - so assuming you go with this answer assumes you go with the default configuration)

Turning UFW on on your box will make it so that your computer does not trust other systems on the LAN / WIFI network - which means that it simply considers them as part of the Wider Internet - so it is as safe to run UFW as it is to rely on a router (safer actually).

What @ultrasawblade said is largely correct and generally good advice - however does not address the problem that, on the Internet anyone between you and your target can intercept your traffic, so following his guidelines - while a good idea generally - does not buy you much in terms of security specific to LAN/WIFI based attacks.  Man-In-The middle attacks, while possible on a LAN, are pretty difficult unless the router is compromised.  (His bullet points focus on mitigating MITM attacks)

You ask about using sudo with strong passwords.  This question would not relate to the security of the box sitting on the LAN/WIFI network.  The answer is, however, complex.

Security is best not viewed as "On or Off", rather it should be viewed in layers and time to compromise.   Like physical security, someone with a battering ram will eventually be able to get in - but the stronger the door the longer it will take and the more signs of forced entry.   Like having more doors / alarms with different locks etc will also slow entry - like having more security layers.

Having a firewall is a security layer.
Requiring SUDO is another layer.
Using SELinux or Apparmour is another layer.
Using a virus scanner is another layer (probably not very applicable).
Not installling stuff you don't need - particularly things like Adobe Flash, and not running executables you don't know you can trust is another layer, as is running an ad / javascript blocker.
Backups are another layer.  (RAID is not backup)
Regularly patching the system is another layer.
Running stuff in VM's is another layer.

Security is thus a balancing act between ease of use, practicality and the value of what you are trying to protect.  The correct solution is something only you can decide based on the tradeoffs - A SYSTEM WHERE YOU USE SUDO AND A UFW WOULD BE ANALOGOUS TO A Windows PC with a firewall and seperated administrator account.